# Fail to search for source RPM - it is on the repo, why i cant find it

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

When I search for a source RPM, I see its on the site, but when using Yum commands via the CLI - there is no match, What am I missing ?

The package is kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.src,  I have created a file "/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Ilan.repo":

```
[root@CentOS73-x64 admin]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Ilan.repo
[CentOS-7.0-Base]
name=CentOS-7.0 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[CentOS-7.0-SOURCE]
name=CentOS-7.0 - Source
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/Source/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[root@CentOS73-x64 admin]#
```

command output:

```
[root@CentOS73-x64 admin]# yum info kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.src
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
CentOS-7.0-Base                                                                                                                                               | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
CentOS-7.0-SOURCE                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
base                                                                                                                                                          | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
(1/7): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                 | 156 kB  00:00:00
(2/7): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 129 kB  00:00:00
(3/7): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                               | 5.7 MB  00:00:00
(4/7): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                            | 3.6 MB  00:00:00
(5/7): CentOS-7.0-Base/group_gz                                                                                                                               | 157 kB  00:00:00
(6/7): CentOS-7.0-SOURCE/primary_db                                                                                                                           | 885 kB  00:00:00
(7/7): CentOS-7.0-Base/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 4.9 MB  00:00:01
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Error: No matching Packages to list
[root@CentOS73-x64 admin]#
```

When look at http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/Source/SPackages/ - it is there !

Answer (score 0):

Yum itself cannot download source rpms. You have to use `yumdownloader` from `yum-utils`.

```
yumdownloader --source kernel
```

Comment: yes, i am using yumdownloader on the operation, but who does the search/info ? yum or yumdownloader ?

Comment: You can use yum to search for *binary* package, and then use yumdownloader for downloading its source package. AFAIK you cannot search for source packages.